# How to add CSS to XMLWorker Parser?

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate a PDF with below HTML and CSS. The HTML part works, however I can't figure out how to add my custom css.

Can anybody help me?

```
    public void GenPDF()
    {
        var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            //<title>Page Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>

            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>

            </body>
            </html>";

        var css = @"body { background:red; }";

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f))
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                document.Open();
                using (var stringReader = new StringReader(html))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                        writer, document, stringReader
                    );
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes("test.pdf", stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use embedded style sheet as follows.

```
var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <style>
            body { background:red; }
            </style>
            <title>Page Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>

            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>

            </body>
            </html>";
```

Comment: Thing is I need to generate multiple PDF's, different HTML but same CSS.